# Insert data into mysql database in loop

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to php and sql language and i got a question.
I want to insert my data into the database while looping. So far, my code is like this.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
$sql="INSERT INTO exec (time, value) VALUES (now(), '34')";
}
```

However, when I execute this code, the data only insert into the database once and not 10 as I intended. I also want to add some delay around 10 seconds between each loop. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't actually query anything, you just build the string in the loop. And why do you want the delay?

Comment: You should always use prepare if you want to reuse the statement. Just creating a string does not do a query.

Comment: ah. I see my mistake. I want the delay so whenever the data was inserted into the database, the time would be different. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a connection to the database and the actual insert.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO exec (time, value) VALUES (now(), 34)");
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
   $stmt->execute();
   sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: put the `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO exec (time, value) VALUES (now(), 34)");` before the loop.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks a lot!

Comment: this works! thanks both of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the query, you are just setting a variable to a string. Thus when the loop ends the string has the last query which is just the one row and it will execute that.

Use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.string.php) like `$sql .= "INSERT ...;";`
Remember to add a ; to the end of your sql statement to allow for multiple queries at the same time.

As an alternative one could also insert multiple values with one insert statement like eg.:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`
   (`field1`, `field2`)
VALUES
   (1, 2),
   (3, 4),
   ...;
```